# It is normal an Identity field increment your value even when a operation fail?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Migration to seed my tables in a SQL Server database with `Update-Database` command. But when this process fail for some reason (FK problem for example), my models with auto-incremental IDs will have their seed incremented.

Let see an example...

A sample Model with auto-incremental ID:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

We can seed this Model in `Configuration.cs` with:

```
context.Persons.AddOrUpdate(t => t.Name,
    new Person { Name = "Alex" },
    new Person { Name = "Louis" },
    new Person { Name = "Willian" }
);
```

Presuming that my database is empty, when i run `Update-Database` I'll have 3 rows in the Person table (Alex, Louis, Willian) with IDs 1, 2 and 3. But if something fails in this process and I run `Update-Database` again but now with success, the IDs will be  4, 5 and 6.

To correct this problem I need to reseed the identity field via SQL.

This is a normal behaviour?
There is something I can do to garantee a sequential ID starting from 1 without removing Identity property and fixing ID values?
There is a better way to populate my tables?

Comment: Yes, it's normal behavior. If e.g. an `INSERT` is rolled back, the identity value that was handed out is "lost". And if you delete away some rows, that doesn't mean the identity value will decrease. Identity values - once dispatched - are **never** "recycled"

Comment: "There is something I can do to garantee a sequential ID" - it's quite "expensive" to achieve this, in terms of being quite a limiting factor to scalability. Be *sure*, really *sure* that you actually **need** your `ID`s to have this property before going down this route. Identity columns should never be shown to your users, and so their actual numeric values should never actually matter.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sadly I'm not a database expert. I use those IDs in relations with another tables. Typical example, I seed two tables called Parent and Child. I expect sequencial IDs in both. Then I can make relations between Parents and Children using that IDs.
I know, the right way is find the rows by another key, like Name, and then retrieving the right ID. But there is a easy way to do that when I'm seeding 10 or more tables with tons of rows and make relations?

Comment: If you're assuming the IDs up front for all of your tables then you may find that, yes, 10 rows were added to the parent table, but e.g. the row that you assumed would receive ID 1 actually received ID 6. If that's fine with you, then I assume that this is just test data - and I wouldn't base a database design constraint on something that's only for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is how identity columns work.  An identity column does not guarantee a monotonically increasing number.  It merely allocates numbers in sequence as necessary so you don't have to do so.

The allocation of an identity can happen before a transaction fails.  The identity is still incremented even if the values are not used.  If you try to correct the value by resetting it, that will cause collisions.

For example, rows 1, 2, and 3 are inserted with the identities 1, 2, and 3.  Then a ROLLBACK occurs, so the rows are removed from the table.  Meanwhile, 4, 5, and 6 are inserted. You see that 1, 2, and 3 were missing, so you set the identity back.  When 1, 2, and 3 are inserted, the identity is now 4, so the next insert will have a duplicate primary key.